# Remapping the screenshot button combo in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, buttons, screenshot

In Windows phone 8.1, they changed the screenshot combo to <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, which I cannot use as my Volume Up button is not working, and it's beyond the warranty period.

Is it possible to remap this back to the old button combo or have a gesture or an onscreen button to take screenshots with/without a developer unlock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot. Windows Phone is not as open as desktop Windows, and do not possess the capability to change what buttons do.

Comment: What about the floating button idea? Does something like that exist?

Comment: I am not familiar with the floating button? Are you referring to the soft-keys that show up when a device manufacturer does not use physical buttons? If so, they still cannot be remapped.

Comment: @caschw no, it's a different thing, have a look here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658 to see how it works on iOS.

Comment: Do you have a source from someone who tried Root Tool and WP internals that this can't be done?

Answer (score 1):

There exists (at least) two utilises that help you gain system level access (including the registry) [Root Tool (pulled from Windows Store last year, but available in link)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/general/root-tool-beta-testing-t3006051) and [WP internals](http://www.wpinternals.net/). These tools are somewhat limited in functionality and model support, but still in development. So it might be possible to remap buttons in current (or future releases, in case someone sees this answer in the a long time after I posted this answer).

Answer (score 0):

The app named Root Tool can be used to interop unlock your phone, change font, change the name of manufacturer and run code to get updates, but there is no option for changing functions for buttons!

Comment: Please specify the tools used, as Windows phone does not have rooting options like android. As far a I know I have not known any tool that can change the system fonts in a Windows phone.

Comment: Ramraj already specified that the tool used it "Root tool" (misspelled "Rool Tool").